# Use of AVG function in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, average

I want to know the top 3 student in my database so I use AVG function but it seems I have some errors this is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT grade.GStudNo, AVG(grade.Grade) as Grade, students.LName, students.FName, students.MName, students.Course
FROM students INNER JOIN grade ON students.StudNo = grade.GStudNo
WHERE GSem = '1st Semester' AND GYear = '2007'
GROUP BY grade.GStudNo
ORDER BY AVG(grade.Grade) ASC")
...
<?php while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo "$myrow[LName] ";echo "$myrow[FName] "; echo "$myrow[MName]"; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "$myrow[Grade]";?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

this is the error message : Notice: Undefined index: Grade in C:\xampp\htdocs\strawman\default.php on line 368

but i defined the AVG(grade.Grade)AS Grade.. :(

Comment: @PiDo: You are saying `but it seems i have some errors `. Could you please post the error messages?

Comment: And those errors would be...?

Comment: What are your errors?  I would start looking at not ordering by a function and also if you include a aggregate column then the select must include aggregates or columns participating in the group by.

Comment: @Hadley - Not in `MySQL` you can group by say `PK` then select the other table columns in the select list. It's the responsibility of the programmer to ensure that only one value can exist for the columns selected but not grouped by as if there are multiple the result is undefined.

Comment: It seems that `$result` is not returning any rows.

Comment: there are multiple student numbers so i use the group by..

Answer (score 1):

MySQL might be confused as you are using the field name `Grade` as alias and use it afterwards in AVG in your ORDER clause again. Try this one (it calls AVG only once):

```
SELECT grade.GStudNo, AVG(grade.Grade) as gradeAverage ... 
ORDER BY gradeAverage ASC
```

And, why are you using double quotes around the variables? That'll be much quicker to process:

```
<?php echo $myrow['LName'] .' '. $myrow['FName'] .' '. $myrow['MName']; ?>
```

Comment: Still `Undefined index: Grade`? Your second Column should now read `<?php echo $myrow['gradeAverage'];?>` so the error should be at least `Undefined index: gradeAverage`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the following syntax:

```
<?php echo "$myrow[LName] ";
```

You'll want to use something like this:

```
<?php echo "$myrow['LName'] ";
```

Or, my preferred syntax when using double quotes:

```
<?php echo "{$myrow['LName']} ";
```

And the same goes for the other variables.

Leaving out the quotes will cause PHP to 'guess' what you mean. It'll go fine sometimes, horribly wrong other times.

Comment: Then could you try the following (inside the `while`-loop) and post the result? `print_r($myrow);`

Comment: this is the result: print_r{(Array)['Grade']}

Comment: `"$myrow[LName]"` is the correct syntax. using single-quoted array keys inside a double-quoted string is incorrect and will spit out a warning. The `{}` version is ok, though.

Comment: Why not just `echo $myrow['LName'];`... No need for more quotes or braces.